# Selecting records greater or equal to 2021 using DATEPART in where clause but still records fo 2019, 2020 are getting returned? why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

```
   select top 10 (DATEPART (year, ss.[dateTime])) 
   from states ss
   where ((DATEPART (year, Cast(ss.[dateTime] as date))) >= (DATEPART (year, 2021)))
```

This returns me data with 2020, 2019 as well why?

The type of `dateTime` column is `DATETIME` and stores values like `2020-10-17 08:20:30.033`.

Comment: Change the `WHERE` clause: `where ((DATEPART (year, Cast(ss.[dateTime] as date))) >= 2021`. Statement `DATEPART (year, 2021)` is and implicit conversion and results in `1905`.

Comment: Why use `DATEPART` at all? Why not use a date boundary, which would be far more performant.

Comment: @Larnu just did that thakns a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, don't use `DATEPART` on your column in there `WHERE` like this in the first place. Such a clause isn't SARGable. Use proper date boundaries:

```sql
SELECT TOP (10)
       DATEPART(YEAR, ss.[dateTime]) AS Year
FROM dbo.states ss
WHERE ss.[dateTime] >= '20210101'
ORDER BY {Expression(s) to order by};
```

If you just want to pass the year, as you're using a parameter, then use `DATEFROMPARTS`: `>= DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,1,1)`

Answer (score 2):

Change the `WHERE` clause and compare the result from `DATEPART()` with an integer value:

```
WHERE ((DATEPART (year, Cast(ss.[dateTime] as date))) >= 2021
```

Statement `DATEPART (year, 2021)` is an implicit conversion (`2021` days after `1900-01-01`) and returns `1905` (which explains the unexpected results).

An additional option (to get the year part of the `[dateTime]` column) is `YEAR()` function:

```
WHERE YEAR(ss.[dateTime]) >= 2021
```

Finally, because performance is always important, consider carefully the explanations in the @Larnu's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be comparing the result from `DATEPART` against the integer `2021`:

```sql
SELECT TOP 10 DATEPART(year, ss.[dateTime])
FROM states ss
WHERE DATEPART(year, CAST(ss.[dateTime] AS date)) >= 2021;
```